# Qual é a origem da palavra "Oxalá"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, origem

Estava a ler o livro *Santos ao ritmo da liturgia* de José Oliveira e no final ds secção do dia 3 de fevereiro diz

> **Oxalá** São Brás lhe traga [referente ao povo arménio] finalmente a paz e a independência a que têm direito, bem como a todos os povos em guerra e escravizados.

Quando perguntado sobre o significado da expressão "Oxalá", o que me ocorreu foi "Se Deus quiser" (*God willing*). Por isso, fiquei curioso em saber mais sobre essa palavra.

Comment: @mdewey não queres pôr isso como uma resposta? Aí poderíamos comentar e votar e etc. :) Tendo em conta o contexto, acho que a definição mais aplicável não é essa de contexto brasileiro e orixá, mas a outra de uso mais genérico que deriva de *inshallah*.

Comment: @ANeves A palavra armenio causou-me algumas dúvidas

Answer (score 4):

É uma palavra que entrou na língua portuguesa durante o período de dominação moura da Península Ibérica, vem do árabe لَوْشَاءَ اللّٰه‎ (lawšāʾa llāh). O fato de parecer com o nome do orixá é coincidental.

Comment: Qual foi a fonte?

Comment: Ergative, +1, mas eu diria que vale mesmo complementar com uma fonte, e.g., o [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/oxal%C3%A1) ou o [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oxal%C3%A1), e incluir o significado da expressão em árabe ("queira deus, se deus quiser").

Comment: Se servir de fonte, segundo o dicionário eletrônico Houaiss da língua portuguesa 3.0: árabe in xálláh 'se Deus quiser' ou, mais provavelmente (seja do ponto de vista fonético ou do ponto de vista semântico), do árabe wa xálláh (pronunciado comumente wo xálláh) 'e queira Deus', provavelmente pelo espanhol (primeiro registrado em 1495).

Comment: Olá, peço desculpas pela demora! @TiagoMartinsPeres, qualquer dicionário etimológico bom vai ter esta mesma resposta, é uma expressão árabe!

Comment: https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/oxal%C3%A1

Comment: https://dicionario.priberam.org/oxal%C3%A1

Comment: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/sobre-a-palavra-oxala/25286

Comment: Perfeito! Muitas palavras árabes entraram no português durante o domínio árabe da Península Ibérica